# RegEx match on multiple date formats

Tags: regex

I have the following RegEx statement that will return a match on a date formats that matches month, day, and year (e.g January 01, 2001)

```
[12]\d|3[01]))|\w+\s\d{2},\s\d{4}
```

I would like to modify it to include matches in an abbreviated month and with or without the comma following the day. So for example matches would include the following:

```
Jan 01 2001

Jan 01, 2001

January 01 2001

January 01, 2001
```

I believe I have part of what is needed with the below, but I can't seem to put it all together. Any help would be appreciated.

```
(Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. 
What is needed:

- Turn the capturing groups in non-capturing groups
- Add word boundaries `\b` before and after the words
- Match numeric ranges with `(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])`
- Match an optional comma `,?` followed by whitespace
- Anchors at beginning `^` and end of string `$`.

You may use:

```
^\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\b (?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]),? \d{4}$
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/gFJWGR/1).

---

As mentioned in the comments, if case insensitivity is required add `(?i)` option at the start of the pattern. If the pattern is in a bigger string, simply remove the anchors:

```
(?i)\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)\b (?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]),? \d{4}
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/gFJWGR/4).

---

By the way, for months such as `June` or `July`, you may simply use `June?` and `July?` instead of `Jun(?:e)?` and `Jul(?:y)?` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I attempted to past some text that I was trying to get it to match and it won't. See new Regex demo here: https://regex101.com/r/gFJWGR/3. Maybe you can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @JadonR Turn on case insensitivity with `(?i)` and remove the anchors if part of a bigger text, see this demo here: https://regex101.com/r/gFJWGR/4

Comment: Here's one more example that doesn't make sense to me. Why doesn't this one match? See link: https://regex101.com/r/gFJWGR/5

Comment: It does not match because I understood that you were validating double digits for the day. You can make the first number optional by using `?`, see : https://regex101.com/r/gFJWGR/6

Comment: Thanks, I must have spent an hour trying to figure it out. What I need to match against seems to change the more I use this. You are a genius sir!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = 'Jan 01 2001\nJan 01, 2001\nJanuary 01 2001\nJanuary 01, 2001'
print(s)
>>>Jan 01 2001
>>>Jan 01, 2001
>>>January 01 2001
>>>January 01, 2001
```

Since an abbreviation for a month is just its first 3 letters, you can use [a-z]* for the rest of letters of the month.

For example,
**(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)** finds 'Jan', and
**[a-z]*** finds 'uary' for January.

```
re.findall(r'(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]* \d{2},?\d{4}',s)
>>>['Jan 01 2001', 'Jan 01, 2001', 'January 01 2001', 'January 01, 2001']
```